# Eclipse Plugin - Popup Menu Extension

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, popup, swt

I am trying to add a new menu item to Eclipse's popupmenus. It really seemed straightforward enough in the examples and tutorials but the menu item itself is never visible. I expect this to work in all views and for basically anything that is a file. I am using Eclipse 3.4. This is the my plugin.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
      <objectContribution
            objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
            id="com.willcodejavaforfood.ExploreHere.contribution1">
         <action
               label="Explore Here"
               class="com.willcodejavaforfood.explorehere.popup.actions.ExploreHereAction"
               menubarPath="additions"
               enablesFor="1"
               id="com.willcodejavaforfood.ExploreHere.newAction">
         </action>
      </objectContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Any idea why it is never visible?

**----edit----**

Turns out my plugin works just fine in version 3.4.2 of Ganymede, but not in the older version 3.4.0 that I previously used.

Comment: Had the same issue.. doesn't work in Package Explorer but in Navigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code in my Eclipse's installation and I am able to see the action in the contextual menu when I right click one of my .c file in the Project explorer's view of the C perspective.

Take care that a Project or a project's sub folder is not a file.

Comment: Hey thanks for trying it. Where in the context menu does it show up?

Comment: That is where I expected it to be. I packaged it into a jar and tried it on another machine with a clean eclipse install but still nothing. You must have done something differently from me.... ? :)

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse 3.4.2. I just copied and pasted your extension in one of my plugin.xml file.

Comment: Works for me too. I'm running 3.5.

Comment: Is your project setup correctly? Does other extension points work?

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try the PDE templates:

File -> New plugin project -> On the last page select create from template and try the **Plugin with popup menu** which description is exactly what you want:

"This template adds a submenu and a new action to a target object's popup menu. This contribution will appear in all viewers where an object of the specified type is selected."

Hope this can help

Manu

Comment: That is actually what I started out with, but that never worked either. I might try and see if I have the latest version of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ICompiliationUnit` instead of IFile

Comment: Thank you but it works in every other version of Eclipse I've tried except in 3.4.0 so this issue has been resolved.